# Function older - Matlab Coursera course

Tags: matlab

I'm working on the following question:

Write a function called older that takes as its input arguments six positive scalar integers: y1, m1, d1, y2, m2, d2, in that order, representing the birthdates of two persons. The variables that start with y stand for the year, m for the month and d for the day. The variables that end in 1 correspond to the first person, while those that end in 2 correspond to the second person. The function returns 1 if the first person is older, 0 if they have the same age, and -1 if the first person is younger. You do not need to check whether the inputs have appropriate values. For example, you may assume that both m1 and m2 are positive integers that are less than 13 and that the day numbers fit with their months.

```
function x = older( y1,m1,d1,y2,m2,d2 )

if d1 > d2 && m1 > m2 && y1 > y2
    x = 1;

elseif d1 < d2 && m1 < m2 && y1 < y2
    x = -1;

else

    x = 0;

end
```

I can't see where I am going wrong! any help would be greatly appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You've **missed several cases** with your code. One possible example is if person 1 was born on **20/07/2010** and person 2 was born on **23/05/2011**. Here both the **days** and **years** of person 1 is **greater** than person 2 **but** the **month** is **less**. Your code would say they are the same age but they aren't, person 1 is older.

The easiest way to approach this is to first check the years. If they differ than we can return. If the years are the same then we need to check the months, if they differ we can return but if they don't we must perform the same check for the days.

---

**Also** it is worth noting that if the year of *person 1 is greater than* the year of *person 2*, *then person 2 is older*. You have mixed this up in your solution (I did too on my first attempt).

---

```
function x = older(y1, m1, d1, y2, m2, d2)

if (y1 == y2)
    if (m1 == m2)
        if (d1 == d2)
            x = 0;
        elseif (d1 > d2)
            x = -1;
        else
            x = 1;
        end
    elseif (m1 > m2)
        x = -1;
    else
        x = 1;
    end
elseif (y1 > y2)
    x = -1;
else
    x = 1;
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Kavanai4](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1552737/kavanai4) stated, there are several cases you've missed. You could account for all of them directly, as per their solution, or you could perhaps try to rework the problem to have fewer if-else cases. Some people find that makes the logic less tricky.

Here's another way of solving the problem. You may have to convert uint8 to double to keep within range, but otherwise this should work. It would keep the if-else cases to a minimum.

```
function x = older(y1, m1, d1, y2, m2, d2)
tmp1 = y1*10000+m1*100+d1;
tmp2 = y2*10000+m2*100+d2;
if tmp1>tmp2
    x=-1;
elseif tmp1<tmp2
    x=1;
else
    x=0;
end
```

Answer (score -2):

You might lack another `end` at the bottom for the `if` statement,

Comment: The `if` statement is terminated with the `end` that is present. MATLAB functions do not need to be terminated with `end` unless there are [local functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions.html) present in the file.